# Preserve Last Modified Date while uploading File

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cffile

I have an application to upload files to a server.
However, when the files are uploaded, the "Date Modified" changes to the current date/time.

Is there a way to preserve the date of the uploaded file? Or is there a way to change the Date Modified on the uploaded file?

The only answer I have found so far uses Java and dates back to 2006 [CFFile and Last Modified Date](https://www.lamoree.com/machblog/index.cfm?event=showEntry&entryId=132B478A-6134-47D6-B11B3F1AEBB90484). Is there a better way to do the same now?

Comment: Native CFML doesn't give one the control over a file that is necessary to perform this action: you *will* need to drop down to Java, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic html file upload does not provide the original modification date from the client o/s. However, there is a simpler way to change the modified date of server files, as of CF9+: [FileSetLastModified()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6ce1.html).

```
FileSetLastModified(result.serverDirectory &"/"& result.serverFile, dateValue )
```